# timeout events are not getting cleared in nodejs http agent

Tags: node.js

While using node http module I am getting following warning:

```
EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

In my code I am no where attaching multiple listner to same event.

Here is sample program:

Test Code

**Client Code**

```
var options = {
    hostname: "127.0.0.1",
    method: 'POST',
    port: 3000
};

var http = require("http");
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 10;

var https = require("https");

var makeRequest = function (callback) {
    var response;
    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            response += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            callback.apply(null, [null , response]);
            return;
        });

    });

    req.on('error', function (e) {
        callback.apply(null, [e , response]);
        return;
    });

  //  req.setTimeout(10000);
    req.setSocketKeepAlive(true);

    req.setTimeout(180000);

    req.on('timeout', function () {
        req.abort();
    });

    req.end();
}

var maxValue = 100;
var j = 1;
var i;
function doIt() {
    for (i= 1; i <= maxValue; i++) {
        makeRequest(function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(arguments);
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        });
    }
}

process.on('exit', function (){
    console.log('Goodbye!');
    console.log(i);
});

doIt();
```

Server code

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require("url");
var path = require("path");


http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1000;

var https = require("https");
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1000;

var count = 0;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    var body = "";
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            sendResponse(res, "Hello");
        }, 1);
    });


}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');


function sendResponse(res,  msg) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(msg);
};
```

What could be the bug ?

Comment: are you sure this is the entire code? it seems that you have a loop somewhere, where it exceeds the "normal" listeners limit, as the "stupid bug" says, use `.setMaxListeners(0)` to remove the limitation and set to infinite listeners.

Comment: @GeoPhoenix this is the complete code. Increasing limit of max listener will not help. As it will result in memory leak.

Comment: i rerun your code on `0.10.22` it doesn't show that message ..

Comment: @GeoPhoenix It is already .0.10.22

Comment: You've provided the code for two applications here. Is the memory leak in the client or server application?